# Is "SET IDENTITY_INSERT" required to insert arbitrary GUID into [uniqueidentifier] column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017, identity, uniqueidentifier

SQL Server 2016 and 2017, Standard Edition

I need to insert raw data (from another table) into a table that has two `uniqueidentifier` columns.

Does this require that I use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Carrier ON`?

Here is the table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parkingspace](
    [ParkingspaceId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AccountId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ParkingspaceType] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ParkingspaceId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ParkingspaceId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Will the following work** without the `IDENTITY_INSERT` option?  (I think it should but the DBA here is very married to the `IDENTITY_INSERT` option.)

```
INSERT INTO Parkingspace 
  (ParkingspaceID,AcountID,ParkingspaceType)
  SELECT * FROM PRODDBCopy.Parkingspace
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql) is only used for columns with the [`IDENTITY` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property).

[`UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql) is merely a data type.

Your insert statement will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check is there a need for the identity insert:

```
SELECT CONCAT(N'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ', QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id])), N'.', QUOTENAME( OBJECT_NAME([object_id])), N' ON;')
FROM sys.identity_columns
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(table_of_your_interest);
```

If the above returns a record, just paste it before your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Identity inserts only apply to identity columns in sql server trying to create non numeric identity columns will produce this error:

> Identity column 'id' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, unencrypted, and constrained to be nonnullable.

No uniqueidentifiers allowed.